# Can Java be truly "non-blocking" with CompletableFuture? Is it possible to handle everything asynchronously with one thread?

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

While I understand that a certain level of concurrency can be achieved with `CompletableFuture` interface, I am not convinced that it is truly non-blocking.

Technically with asynchronous IO, shouldn't one be able to handle everything with just one thread since non-blocking means that a thread can `leave one process, do something else and come back later`.

```
thread0                        same/ another thread
    |
    | 
    |
(makes a http request) --------- P2
                                  |
                                  | handle request's followups (e.g. .then())
                                  |
(finishes the request) -----------
    |
    |
   end
```

[image]

Comment: You are conflating 'non-blocking' with 'asynchronous'. They aren't the same thing. Any time you reach a rendezvous in asynchronous programming somebody is going to block. That doesn't stop it being asynchronous, which is all it is intending to be.

Comment: @user207421 I understand it is going to `wait` when there is a rendezvous. What I am talking about is that in javascript the `waiter` can do something else while waiting(non-blocking), but it can't in java CompletableFuture.get() (blocking). Did I understand it wrongly?

Comment: You would not call `CompletableFuture.get`, because that does, as you say, block the current thread. Just like in Javascript, you would "map" over it (add a `.then` handler). You end up with another `ComputableFuture`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but only if all the work being done by all code is non-blocking. A lot of existing libraries contain blocking IO. If they do that on your only thread, everything else will have to wait. And there is nothing in the language to prevent you from doing it.

The usual approach to this problem is to set aside one or more thread pools for blocking workloads (and wrap them in code that makes sure execution gets shifted to those).

Also, even if everything is non-blocking, you probably still want to have as many threads as you have CPU cores (in order to be able to take advantage of those).

Comment: Thanks @Thilo,  can you please elaborate more on `setting aside one or more thread pools for blocking workloads`?

Comment: You do not just call `blockingFunction()`. Instead you do something like `ioExecutorService.submit(() -> blockingFunction)` and receive a `CompletableFuture`. That `ioExecutorService` will have to create additional threads to handle the blocking code (that you did not want to run on your main scheduler thread).

Answer (score 1):

CompletableFuture itself is always non-blocking. 
Blocking can happen only if a user passes a blocking method as a parameter to a CompletableFuture's method.